# Separate Babel config for tooling in Gatsby project

Tags: javascript, babeljs, gatsby

I'd like to use [babel-presest-gatsby](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-gatsby) for a Gatsby project which Gatsby would use by default if there is no babel-configuration in the root of the project, however I have other tooling co-located in the project that needs specific babel config, and that config causes problems with how Gatsby handles code-splitting. Equally, using Gatsby's preset causes problems for the tooling. This means I need some way to completely separate the two sets of babel config. One set of config for Gatsby, one set for tooling.

The problem is that if I place a babel config file at the root of the project, the tooling will use it, but so will Gatsby (causing code-splitting issues).

Gatsby provides [an API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/) to manipulate the babel-config via:

- [setBabelOptions](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#setBabelOptions)
- [setBabelPlugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#setBabelPlugin)
- [setBabelPreset](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#setBabelPreset)

I had hoped I could use this API to completely replace the config with Gatsby's default, but they only allow the project-root config to be patched, meaning that I hit the same problem with code-splitting. Ideally Gatsby would provide and API to `replaceBabelConfig` as it does with Webpack, but it doesn't.

**How can I have two separate babel configs, one for Gatsby, one for tooling?**

Answer (score 0):

**This breaks chunking in Gatsby 5.**

I have used an env that is only present when the babel config is loaded by Gatsby to toggle between configs:

babel.config.js

```
const isGatsby = !!process.env.gatsby_executing_command


module.exports = isGatsby
  ? {
      presets: [`babel-preset-gatsby`],
    }
  : {
      ... own config
    }
```